# character group of finite abelian group and induced homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

This is ex 5.7 of chapter 10 of artin's algebra (2nd edition)

Suppose $\varphi:G \rightarrow G'$ is a homomorphism of abelian groups. Define an induced homomorphism $\hat{\varphi}" \hat{G'} \rightarrow \hat{G}$ between their character groups. Then prove that $\varphi$ is into iff $\hat{\varphi}$ is onto.

I know that if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then we have $G \cong \hat{G}$. But I don't know how to define the right induced homomorphism. I even suspected that the $'$ sign is in the wrong side. Please helps.

Answer (score 1):

This induced homomorphism is right-composition with $\varphi$: it is $\hat\varphi:\alpha\mapsto\alpha\circ\varphi$, where $\alpha\in\hat{G'}$. This is just the general fact that right-composition with a surjective map is injective.

In particular this does not require using any unnatural isomorphism $G \cong\hat{G}$.

To prove injectivity explicitly, just proceed as usual: either assume $\alpha\circ\varphi=\beta\circ\varphi$ and deduce $\alpha=\beta$ from this, or for the contrapositive assume $\alpha\neq\beta$ and prove $\alpha\circ\varphi\neq\beta\circ\varphi$. For the first approach, you need to prove (with the given hypothesis) that for any $g'\in G'$ one has $\alpha(g')=\beta(g')$; to do this it suffices to write $g'=\varphi(g)$, which is possible by surjectivity, and apply the hypothesis.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment for the above answer. Marc's comment is correct but it is not the question asked. It asks us to prove $\phi$ is injective iff $\hat{\phi}$ is surjevtive, however Marc only show if $\phi$ is surjective then $\hat{\phi}$ is injective.

Comment: Indeed, I see I got the into and ontos interchanged. The argument becomes a bit more complicated for the other case.